# TCL how to require both operands to determine result in IF statement

Tags: vbscript, tcl

new to TCL and running into a short circuit issue it seems.  Coming from vbscript, I'm able to perform this properly, but trying to convert to a TCL script I'm having issues with the short circuit side effect and have been trying to find the proper way of doing this.

In the following snippet, I want to execute "do something" only if BOTH sides are true, but because of short circuiting, it will only evaluate the second argument if the first fails to determine the value of the expression.

```
    if {$basehour != 23 && $hours != 0} {
        do something
    }
```

Maybe I'm not searching for the right things, but so far I've been unable to find the solution.  Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `&&` operator *always* does short-circuiting in Tcl (as it does in C and Java and a number of other languages too). If you want the other version and can guarantee that both sub-expressions yield booleans (e.g., they come from equality tests such as you're doing) then you can use the `&` operator instead, which does bit-wise AND and will do what you want when working on bools. If you're doing this, it's wise to put parentheses around the sub-expressions for clarity; while everyone remember the precedence of `==` with respect to `&&`, the order w.r.t. `&` is often forgotten. (The parentheses are free in terms of execution cost.)

```
if {($basehour != 23) & ($hours != 0)} {
    do something
}
```

However, it's usually not necessary to do this. If you're wanting an AND that you're feeding into a boolean test (e.g., the `if` command's expression) then there's no reason to not short-circuit, as in your original code; if the first clause gives false, the second one won't change what value the overall expression produces.